# Add a new mailid in outlook by clicking on email id in a mail body

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

I want to generate a mail body in which i want to make a link, on which user clicks and add new contact outlook popup opens into the client screen.

How this can be done??

Comment: but my client requirement is that, he want to make this at any how.... I have too much tried but i failed. can any one have the solution of this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what [vCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) was invented for. Create a vCard file (from Outlook or using a third party application), and host it online on some webspace. Or, if needed, you can create a webpage that generates the vCard dynamically. Simply add a hyperlink to the vCard URL to the email message body.

Upon clicking upon the URL, Outlook will open up the contents from the vCard as a new Outlook contact.

---

That is, if Outlook isn't setup to block URLs, in which case you'd be better off sending the vCard as an attachment. Outlook signatures can be setup [to contain a vCard](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290840).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this will most likely turn out to be impossible. Scripting is usually taboo in E-Mail clients.

This *may* be possible from within a web site using IE specific scripting (in VBScript, connecting to Outlook via COM or something), but security settings would block that from working for the vast majority of users anyway.